# iOS iPhone iPad Simulator

Tags: objective-c

This is what I get when I test my iPhone code on iPadPro 12.9 inch 2nd generation simulator. Isn't there a discrepancy ? Thanks, David.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you make your project an universal app ? Apple docs state, that this value should be used on universal  applications (exclusively?). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620037-userinterfaceidiom?language=objc

Comment: No. I am trying to submit an App to the Store. The is iPhone only , but they insist it should be able to run also on iPad (!!) . It never occurred for me but I have not submitted many and not in the last year, so maybe it is legitimate. Anyway I have to know if I run on iPad so I can produce a rejection page.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using this UIDeviceHardware instead of checking the interface idiom:
https://github.com/fahrulazmi/UIDeviceHardware/blob/master/UIDeviceHardware.m

```
NSString *platformString = [UIDeviceHardware platformString];
```

I've been using it for awhile now, and it works perfectly for me.

However, there is a problem when using it on simulator. When running on simulator, the platform is equal to x86_64 or i386 which will simply return iPad or iPhone. So ... I feel like you won't find a satisfying conclusion unless you tested this on a real device or at least got someone to test it for you on a real device.

In your case, you would check for one of these two platform strings:
"iPad Pro 12.9-inch (WiFi)" or "iPad Pro 12.9-inch (Cellular)"
https://github.com/fahrulazmi/UIDeviceHardware/blob/master/UIDeviceHardware.m#L83-L84

A good way to check for those is to just check for the prefix:
`[platforString hasPrefix:"iPad Pro 12.9-inch"]`

Comment: I have done something like that but it is still strange .